# FileMaker 6 and AppleScript: Deleting a Menu Item

Tags: snow-leopard, applescript, menu-bar

I am trying to write an AppleScript to delete or at least disable certain menu items in FileMaker pro 6. My documentation indicates that it can be done, yet even the exact examples that they give, do not work.

Here are a few examples of some that I tried with their results:

delete menu item "Delete All Records…" of menu "Records" --this compiles, but returns the error 'Event not handled'

disable menu item "Delete All Records…" of menu "Records" --This does not even compile

I also tried similar approaches with System Events to no avail.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I need to prevent users from deleting critical records from a database.

Comment: Woah - Blast from the past with 2002 era software. Are you running 10.1 which matches the introduction of that software or some newer version of OS X?

Comment: I am using 10.6.8

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to change the user permissions so they can't delete records that the scripts use. Then you can remove the full access from those scripts. Hard to tell without looking over your shoulder or seeing something like a DDR for the database in question.